# Foundation 4 dropdown button appearing too high

Tags: jquery, css, sass, zurb-foundation

*Some prereqs:*

**Hello everyone, first let me direct you to the site in question: 
http://hws-1.apphb.com/Account/Smartplan**

On top of the table you will notice a blue and green dropdown button as provided by Zurb's Foundation 4.

We are using ASP.net MVC with the Zurb Foundation w/ SASS nuget package.

*The problem:*

If you click on the dropdown buttons you will notice that they appear halfway through the buttons.  The intended functionality is to begin right underneath them as shown on the zurb dropdown button docs.

I've done a bit of research and have found posts relating to dropdown issues, but they were all a slightly different problem (the drop down showing way off), and were on an older version of foundation 4.  I am using 4.3.1 as provided by the Nuget package.  I have read that the issues regarding the dropdown have been resolved since 4.1.6 as per this thread mostly:

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1789

I am looking to find the cause of this problem, instead of hardcoding a CSS value to push it farther down.  I have been at it for the past few days trying multiple fixes but nothing has worked.

Has anyone experienced this issue or can provide some insight?  Many thanks to all who reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see the your source code...
problem is zepto.js  is overriding some dropdown.js protocols..

remove your zepto.js

```
   <script src="https://media.hardworkingsoftware.com/Scripts/zepto.js"></script>
```

When you are using foundation add the zepto.js whenever it is required..

```
   <script>
   document.write('<script src=https://media.hardworkingsoftware.com/Scripts/'
   + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
   + '.js><\/script>');
   </script>
```

for more see this link http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

Comment: I must have misread the documentation, I thought it said that Zepto was required to run certain components, but it appears that Jquery will take care of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I know the calculation is actually being done in javascript but as a quick workaround, go to your CSS file

```
.f-dropdown {
    margin-top: 33px;
}
```

And it should fix your issue

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of a hardcoded CSS solution, but would prefer to use it as a last ditch effort.  I fear it might have other ramifications throughout the site.

I am curious if the problem lay within the amount of div nesting...

Thanks again

Comment: this is a solid workaround. Just make sure you scope the CSS so that it only affects the specific dropdown you are trying to move, and this wont have any site wide ramifications.  For example: div#your_element_id.f-dropdown { margin-top: 10px }